# Select Tasks without ActiveSelection using Project VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I take a project and export selected tasks into a Gantt chart in Excel.

The tasks that end up in the Excel chart are selected by highlighting them in Project and then running the macro. I would like for the macro to select these tasks by looking at the first and last task of that group. What I mean is I'd like to read the task names, find Task Name "A" and then process all the tasks afterwards until it hits Task Name "Z".

I tried to use the Task ID to set the ID numbers but the task number will change whenever new tasks are added to the project. I also tried using the unique ID but that won't work since there are some tasks between A and Z that have been in the project for a while so setting a specific range for that wouldn't work either.

I feel there is a simple way to do this but I just haven't stumbled upon it yet.

EDIT: Added the code below. The relevant section is just below the comment "Fill cells with Task information".

```
Sub ExportToExcel()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim proj As Project
Dim t As Task
Dim pj As Project
Dim pjDuration As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim c As Range
Set pj = ActiveProject
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

'AppActivate "Excel"
xlApp.Visible = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Controls\Desktop\ServiceSchedule.xlsx")
xlApp.WindowState = xlMaximized

'Set up Project Detail Headers
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
xlSheet.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xlSheet.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
xlSheet.UsedRange.Delete
xlSheet.Cells.Clear
xlSheet.Cells.ClearContents
'xlSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Project Name"
'xlSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = pj.Name
'xlSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Project Title"
'xlSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = pj.Title
'xlSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Project Start"
'xlSheet.Cells(1, 5).Value = pj.ProjectStart
'xlSheet.Cells(2, 4).Value = "Project Finish"
'xlSheet.Cells(2, 5).Value = pj.ProjectFinish

'Set Gantt Chart Timespan
'xlSheet.Cells(1, 7).Value = "Project Duration"
pjDuration = 90
'xlSheet.Cells(1, 8).Value = pjDuration & "d"

'Set up Headers
xlSheet.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Task ID"
xlSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value = "Task Name"
xlSheet.Cells(4, 3).Value = "Name"
xlSheet.Cells(4, 4).Value = "Task Start"
xlSheet.Cells(4, 5).Value = "Task Finish"
xlSheet.Cells(4, 1).Font.Bold = True
xlSheet.Cells(4, 2).Font.Bold = True
xlSheet.Cells(4, 3).Font.Bold = True
xlSheet.Cells(4, 4).Font.Bold = True
xlSheet.Cells(4, 5).Font.Bold = True

'Freeze Rows & Columns
xlSheet.Range("F5").Select
xlSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'AutoFit Header columns and Hide blank rows
xlSheet.Columns("A:E").AutoFit
xlSheet.Columns("A").Hidden = True
xlSheet.Rows("1:2").Hidden = True

' Add day of the week headers for the entire Project's duration

For i = 0 To pjDuration
'If Today's Date is Sunday
    If xlSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now()) = 1 Then
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).Value = Now() + i
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@"
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).Value = Now() + i
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).NumberFormat = "ddd"
    End If
'If Today's Date is Monday
    If xlSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now()) = 2 Then
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 1) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@"
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 1) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).NumberFormat = "ddd"
    End If
 'If Today's Date is Tuesday
    If xlSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now()) = 3 Then
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 2) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@"
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 2) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).NumberFormat = "ddd"
    End If
'If Today's Date is Wednesday
    If xlSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now()) = 4 Then
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 3) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@"
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 3) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).NumberFormat = "ddd"
    End If
'If Today's Date is Thursday
    If xlSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now()) = 5 Then
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 4) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@"
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 4) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).NumberFormat = "ddd"
    End If
'If Today's Date is Friday
    If xlSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now()) = 6 Then
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 5) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@"
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 5) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).NumberFormat = "ddd"
    End If
'If Today's Date is Saturday
    If xlSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Now()) = 7 Then
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 6) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmmm d, yyyy;@"
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).Value = (Now() - 6) + i
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).NumberFormat = "ddd"
    End If

'Color Weekend columns
    xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).ColumnWidth = 10
    If xlSheet.Application.Cells(4, i + 6).Text = "Sat" Then
       For k = 1 To 100
        xlSheet.Cells(4 + k, i + 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        Next
       End If
    If xlSheet.Application.Cells(4, i + 6).Text = "Sun" Then
        For k = 1 To 100
        xlSheet.Cells(4 + k, i + 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
       Next
       End If
Next

'Merge date cells

For i = 0 To pjDuration Step 7
    xlSheet.Cells(3, i + 6).Select
    xlSheet.Application.ActiveCell.Resize(1, 7).Select
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Merge
Next i    

'Fill cells with Task information
Dim SearchString1 As String
Dim SearchString2 As String
SearchString1 = "Buyoffs/Service"
SearchString2 = "History"

**For Each t In ActiveSelection.Tasks
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 1).Value = t.ID
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 2).Value = t.Name
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 3).Value = t.ResourceNames
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 4).Value = t.Start
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 4).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mm-dd-yy;@"
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 5).Value = t.Finish
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, 5).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mm-dd-yy;@"**

'Loop to color cells to mimic Gantt chart
    For i = 5 To pjDuration + 5
        If t.Start <= xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 1) And t.Finish >= xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 1) Then
            xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            With xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4, i + 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ThemeColor = 1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
    End With
        End If
     Next i
Next t

'Loop To Change Day Headers to Single Char Format
For i = 0 To pjDuration
 With xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6)
        If .Text = "Sun" Then
            .Value = "S"
        ElseIf .Text = "Mon" Then
            .Value = "M"
        ElseIf .Text = "Tue" Then
            .Value = "T"
        ElseIf .Text = "Wed" Then
            .Value = "W"
        ElseIf .Text = "Thu" Then
            .Value = "R"
        ElseIf .Text = "Fri" Then
            .Value = "F"
        ElseIf .Text = "Sat" Then
            .Value = "S"
        End If
    End With
 xlSheet.Cells(4, i + 6).ColumnWidth = 1.5
Next

'Remove empty rows

xlSheet.Range("A5:A10000").AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False

'Autofit Columns
xlSheet.Columns("B:E").AutoFit
xlSheet.Columns("B:B").Select
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.ColumnWidth = 50
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With    

'Format Cells with Borders
    xlSheet.Rows("4:4").Select
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Columns("E:E").Select
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Range("F4:CR4").Select
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    xlSheet.Application.Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

xlApp.Visible = True
xlBook.Save
xlSheet.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
xlSheet.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
xlSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100

End Sub
```

Comment: show the macro. show the sample data. we can't guess at what you've written or what the data looks like

Comment: Sorry. Added it above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured something out. Not the way I initially had in mind but it worked. I used the WBS property of Project to skip any task with outline level "1". So it would start at outline level "2" which contained what I wanted. Ending the loop was easy sine I just needed an If statement to jump out of the loop when it came across that last task name.

```
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
If t.Name = "History" Then
Exit For
End If
If t.Name = "Vacations" Then
   TaskA = t.ID
End If
If t.Name = "Buyoffs/Service" Then
   TaskB = t.ID
End If
If t.Name = "Buyoffs/Service" Then GoTo NextIteration
TaskOffset = TaskB - TaskA + 1
If t.Name = "Vacations" Then GoTo NextIteration
If t.Name = "Unscheduled" Then GoTo NextIteration
If InStr(1, t.WBS, "1.") Then GoTo NextIteration
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4 - TaskOffset, 1).Value = t.ID
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4 - TaskOffset, 2).Value = t.Name
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4 - TaskOffset, 3).Value = t.ResourceNames
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4 - TaskOffset, 4).Value = t.Start
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4 - TaskOffset, 4).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mm-dd-yy;@"
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4 - TaskOffset, 5).Value = t.Finish
    xlSheet.Cells(t.ID + 4 - TaskOffset, 5).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mm-dd-yy;@"
```